# Measuring Integrating Capital Market

Tags: macroeconomics

There are several methods measuring integration capital market. What best to measure for integration capital market?

Comment: Please expand your question. It is not clear what you are asking. Specifically, what do you mean by "integration"?

Comment: The question needs more clarification. There is a large literature on market integration like: 1. Levine, R., 1997. Financial Development and Economic Growth: Views and Agenda. Journal of Economic Literature 35 (2). 2.  Kose, M. A., Prasad E., Rogoff, K., Wei S-J, 2006. Financial Globalization: A
Reappraisal. IMF Working Paper. 3.  Gultekin, M. N., Gultekin, N. B. and Penati, A., 1989. (omitted). Journal of Finance 44, 849-869.  4. Mendoza, E. G., Quadrini, V. and Ríos-Rull, J.-V., 2009. (omitted). Journal of Political Economy
Vol. 117, No. 3.